# How to understand dart async operation?

Tags: ios, dart

As we know, dart is a single-threaded language. So according to the document, we can use Futrure/Stream to implement a async opetation. It sends the time-consuming operation to the Event Queue.
What confused me is where the Event Queue working on. It is working on the dart threat? if yes, it will block the app.
Another question is Event Queue a FIFO queue. If i have two opertion, one is a 1mins needed networking request, the other is a click event. The two operation will send to the Event Queue.
So if the click event will blocked by the networking request? Because the queue is a FIFO queue?
So where is the event queue working on?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that asynchronous and multithreading are two different things. Dart uses Futures and `async/await` to achieve asynchronicity, but Dart is still inherently a single-threaded language.

The way it works is when a Future is created (either manually or via calling an `async` method), that process is added to an event queue, as you read. Then, in the middle of all the synchronous execution, whenever there is a lull, the event queue can take priority. It can then go through the processes and figure out if any of the Futures have been completed. If so, the result is passed along to any other asynchronous processes that are waiting on that resource, if any.

This also means that, yes, if your program hangs in the middle of an asynchronous operation (with the easy example of an endless loop via `while (true) {}`), it will freeze the entire program, including the synchronous code and other asynchronous processes still waiting to resolve (even if the conditions allowing them to resolve have already occurred).

However, in your case, this won't be an issue. If you fire an asynchronous process in the form of a network request followed by another in the form of a "click event" (not sure what you're referring to, but I'll assume it's asynchronous as well), they will both be added to the event queue in that order. But if the click event resolves before the network request, the event queue will merely recognize that the network request Future has not yet resolved and will move on to the click event that has.

As a side note, it's worth noting that Dart *does* have a multi-threading capability, albeit in a fairly roundabout way. Dart has something called an Isolate, which isn't a thread but a completely separate child program. This means that the Isolate cannot access any of the same data in memory as the root program itself. However, data can be passed between the two using `SendPort`s and `ReceivePort`s. This makes using Isolates slightly more complicated than threads, but it also means that, if no memory is shared, it virtually eliminates race conditions based on which thread accesses the memory first.

Comment: Thank you for response. As you say, it will freeze the entire program if the asynchronous operation using while (true) {}. So if i download a big file using Future,and then i tap a button. So the button will not reponsed?

Comment: @porthuas The download of the file will happen in the background, handled by whatever underlying HTTP component the platform. The purpose of the Future in this instance is to notify your code when the file is finished downloading, not to handle the downloading process itself. Unless the HTTP module you are using was horrendously designed, the act of making an HTTP call (such as downloading a file) will not cause the program to hang while waiting for it to complete.

Comment: @ Abion47 Got it! So if the event queue have two event A and B ， the A will block the B?  Is that right?

Comment: @porthuas You seem to be under the impression that the event queue is only capable of processing one Future at a time, waiting for one to complete before moving to the next. On each event loop, _all_ the Futures get processed. The event queue just describes the _order_ in which Futures will be processed, even if "processing" just means recognizing a Future is not yet complete. If A is before B in the queue but B finishes first, A won't block B.

Comment: Thank you! I had made the following code, and the out put is getTest->test->getTest2. Can you explain it. `main(List<String> args) {
  print("main function start");
  var b = getTest();
  var b1 = getTest2();

  b1.then((v){
    print(v);
  });

  b.then((v){
    print(v);
  });
  print("main function end");
}
Future<String> getTest() {
  return Future<String>(() {
    for(var i = 0; i< 1000000; i++){
      print(i);
    }
    return "getTest";
  });
}

Future<String> getTest2() {
  return Future<String>(() {
    print("test");
    return "getTest2";
  });
}`

Comment: @porthuas The event loop for the Futures doesn't start until the `main` method finishes. Then the Futures execute in the order in which they were added to the event queue... in this case `getTest` first, `getTest2` second. Neither of the Futures `await` at any point, so they will execute fully before proceeding to the next Future. So the order of operations is: `getTest` Future -> 1 million number for loop -> `return "getTest"` -> `print("getTest")` -> `getTest2` Future -> `print("test")` -> `return "getTest2"` -> `print("getTest2")`.

Comment: @ Abion47 If i want the resuit to be getTest2->getTest, How should i do with the code. Thank you!

Comment: Either declare the futures in the other order or do something in `getTest` that causes it to take longer like `await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));`

Comment: Finially, i got it. Thank you very much!